# How to add icon for different file type in sublime 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want to switch my text editor to Sublime text 2 but the only issue cant let me do it.

I work with big projects and need very quick to navigate between files. ST2 sidebar doesnt support icon packs on such files .css, .html, ,php, .js etc. I found some article where the one guy explains how to do that - https://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/19274-theming-of-the-sidebar/ I tried it but nothing happens. I tried do changes on the user-settings file. I suppose I do something wrong

[image]

If somebody knows how to do this please help

Comment: Where *"the one guy"* explained it? There are 80 replies on that page! Please [edit] your question to give exact details of what you did, including which changes you made to what files, and the exact location of anything you downloaded. To my knowledge file-type icons are not supported for Sublime Text 2 (it's been a major complaint), although they were recently introduced in Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 1):

The newest stable version of Sublime Text 3 has sidebar themeing and many themes (not colour schemes) have added support for custom icons.

So upgrade to this: http://www.sublimetext.com/3

and then either use the default theme, or something like Soda theme to get custom sidebar icons.

Comment: I have Sublime Text 3 and `Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme` theme currently selected. I see icons in sidebar only for folders. File lacks icons completely (there is an empty space before file name, but no icon at all). What am I missing?

Comment: @trejder As I see sublime 3 is on beta now. So it can have some other bugs which I dont want to be faced too

Comment: @yevgeniy ST3 is indeed in beta, but from what I've learnt from their support -- it will most likely be always in beta! :] They have only one developer, small income from paid licenses, so here are the results. Look at dates, one general update per 1-1,5 year! While working with beta on production environment may seem wrong, take into consideration, that with one developer they at least are doing something to ST3, while works or ST2 has probably stopped for good (last update over a year ago, previous -- over two years ago). So, in my opinion, using ST3 is better of two wrong decisions! :]

Comment: @trejder Actually I tried ST3 a couple hours ago. But it is doesnt make sense. There is an icons but there are only two types and doesnt help me anyway. So the question is still open. Maybe there is a way to change defaults

Answer (score 1):

For ST3 users. Adding icons for different file types and folders to default theme:

1. Download [archive](http://xaviesteve.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Theme-Default.zip) with icons. Or [this one](http://vk.com/doc41811039_437399033?hash=f3943880d159410861&dl=00f4743c2cbc4c09c9).
2. Go to Preferences > Browse Packages (In Windows find the Browse packages button to open the packages folder)
3. Copy(extract) folder from archive to packages folder. If you already have a
   `Theme - Default` folder then just merge them.
4. Done. Thanks to [Xavi Esteve](http://xaviesteve.com/5300/sublime-text-3-sidebar-icons-default-theme/)

2023 UPDATE:

There is [FileIcons](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileIcons) you can install to get different file icons depending on file extension